# Disable Device Enollment Notification Window

Tags: macos, mobile-device-management

I desire to disable the "Device Enrollment" notification window for OS X machines that are enrolled in DEP (Apple's Device Enrollment Program). The machines are running 10.11, though the process should be the same for 10.10.

(While we are currently managing iOS devices, we are not managing OS X devices through the enrollment program, and I do not want the pop-up to confuse or distract students.)

I have not found a way to disable to the pop-up, or where the setting is stored, once the user hits "Skip".  Does anyone know where this setting is stored, or perhaps how I can modify it using "defaults write" or something similar?

Comment: I believe the LaunchAgent that controls this can be found at /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ManagedClientAgent.enrollagent.plist - However "System Integrity Protection" in El Capitan prevents me from disabling the service. Any ideas?

Comment: Disable System Integrity Protection in Recovery Mode by holding Comment-R during restart. Open Terminal in the recovery screen and type:
"csrutil disable" (without quotes) then restart computer. From there can edit .plist file

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To disable enrollment pop-ups, I moved 2 files...

```
/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ManagedClientAgent.enrollagent.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.ManagedClient.enroll.plist
```

to `/Library/LaunchAgentsDisabled` and `/Library/LaunchDaemonsDisabled` (make sure to create the directories if they don't exist).

Since I am using El Capitan, I am not "allowed" to modify the System folder. I did so by using Target Disk Mode and connecting to a Yosemite machine. You could also do so by disabling System Integrity Protection (instructions at http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/ )

Comment: moved those two files, but still getting this pop up. Any other files needed to be removed?

Comment: I assumed you either restarted the machine or unloaded the LaunchAgent and LaunchDaemon?

Comment: Will a reboot bring these back automatically?

Comment: @KirkOuimet - No.  Launchd loads daemons from /System/Library/LaunchDaemons and from /Library/LaunchDaemons.  If the file is not there, it can not load it.  Please note that in El Capitan, you must disable or work around SIP in order to move these files.

Comment: On macOS Sierra I couldn't find the files `/System/Library/Launch*/com.apple.ManagedClient*`. Where are they located on Sierra?

Comment: @jfoliveira Sorry, I don't have a machine running Sierra at the moment. Will have to see if someone else responds.

Comment: @jfoliveira , on Sierra those files are in the same locations, i tested it today and worked.

Comment: This solution worked on Sierra, but not on High Sierra (10.1.13). I get a `mv: rename LaunchAgents/com.apple.ManagedClientAgent.enrollagent.plist to LaunchAgentsDisabled: No such file or directory` error message. Has anyone else tried it on the latest OS update?

Comment: @allenslee I don't have a High Sierra machine with me at the moment to test. Did you first create the directory /Library/LaunchAgentsDisabled ?

Comment: @TimDearborn apologies, looks like i was in the wrong directory. I was in `Users/Library`, not `System/Library`

The solution still works on High Sierra.

Comment: How do we do this on Mojave?